# Un-combining notifications on HTC M9/Lollipop?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, notifications, htc-one

On my HTC One M9 with Android Lollipop, notifications are combined by category. For example, if I have 3 emails and 5 text messages, the notification list will show two items - "3 new emails" and "5 new messages" (or however it's worded). This is great on the lock screen, but it's causing problems for my smartwatch, which will say I only have 2 notifications instead of 7. The smartwatch only lets me read full emails and texts through their notifications, and sometimes it will fail to load the bodies of emails when they have been combined into one notification. The notification settings on the smartwatch are not customizable so I can't adjust anything there.

Is there any way to stop Lollipop (or Sense, whichever is responsible) from combining notifications? I'd rather receive a separate notification for each text and email if that will make them easier to read on my watch.

Comment: I think this depends on how the developer implemented their notifications on their apps. AFAIK, I don't know if it can be separated, since it needs modification to the app.